# Can I open a text file in Preview from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, preview, file

I know that I can open a file with an external program from the Terminal with `open`, and that works for most applications. However, when I try to use a command like `open -a Preview info.txt`, it launches Preview, but the file is not opened.

I am on Mavericks 10.10.2.

Is there a way to use the `open` command (or any other built-in command) to actually *open* a file in Preview from the Terminal?

Comment: Preview cannot open text files, but the command `open -a Preview photo.jpg` works for me, it opens the image in Preview.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Preview only works with PDF files and some image files (png, jpg, gif, tiff, bmp) so you won't be able to open a text file on Preview.

To open your info.txt file from terminal you need to choose an application that can open text files, like TextEdit or any other text editor.

You also could use `open -e file`, to open any file using TextEdit.

Comment: If you don't want to risk editing the file, try `open -a Safari info.txt`.

Comment: I don't think the question was about opening a text file. There is still the question *how to open a pdf file in Preview from the terminal?*. You failed to answer that question.

Comment: There is no question on 'how to open a pdf file in preview', as the user stated on his example, he already knew how to open files in Preview from the terminal but didn't understood why it didn't worked when trying to open a txt file.

I just answered explaining what kind of files you can open with Preview and how to open any file from the terminal using the default text editor.

Also, other users answered the same, using another example with a image file.

But you've got a point, I could have had answered in a better way.

Answer (score 7):

> **NB** - If there are
>   any further questions about this answer please comment.

**UPDATE**

There's nothing wrong with the other answers, this one leverages a system command to convert the text file to a compatible filetype for Preview (i.e. PDF).

Given a sample file  you can run:

`cupsfilter info.txt > info.pdf`

(to hide the debug output use `cupsfilter info.txt > info.pdf 2> /dev/null`)

After which one may apply the original answer to open the new `info.pdf` file in Preview. You can learn more by running `man cupsfilter`. I believe this just exposes the basic Save As PDF functionality that exists in the CUPS print system.

([Source](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091124090053385))

**Additionally**

As noted in the comments one can simply pipe the command to open a file directly into Preview. This worked for me:

`cupsfilter info.txt 2> /dev/null | open -f -a Preview`

**(Original Answer)**

To open a supported Preview file from Terminal, such as pdf, png, jpg, gif, tiff, bmp:

`open -a Preview <nameOfSupportedFileType>`

*So for example:*

`open -a Preview avatarMask@2x.png`

Opens the png from the current folder in Preview.

Comment: Nice! I tried `cupsfilter` but it didn't occur to me to redirect stderr (doh!). With the redirect you can pipe stdout directly to `open` ( `cupsfilter info.txt 2> /dev/null | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app` )

Answer (score 2):

There is, but you need to convert the file to postscript or PDF first. For example, I have a function `pman` which works exactly like regular `man`, but opens the `man` page in Preview.app:

```
pman () 
{ 
    man -t $* | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
}
```

The `-t` option tells `man` that the output needs to be formatted (using `groff`) as postscript.

You want to open a text file in Preview.app. For the "convert to PDF" stage I use `paps`, which I installed using `brew`:

```
brew install paps
```

After that, it's easy!

```
paps info.txt | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
```

That'll open `info.txt` in Preview. If you do this a lot, you'll probably want to create a function (in your `~/.bash_profile` or similar):

```
preview ()
{
    if [ -z "$*" ]; then
        echo "Usage: preview [FILE]"
    else
        paps $1 | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
    fi
}
complete -f -X '!*.txt' preview
```

Answer (score 2):

> QuickLook scans file contents before you open those files. Usually this just lets you view a file quickly. But you can also use this same technology from the command line to bring about a change to the Finder without actually opening a file. To access QuickLook from the command line, use qlmanage.
>
> `qlmanage -p ~/Desktop/MyTowel42.pdf`
>
> — Charles Edge

You can add following function to `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
preview () { qlmanage -p "$*" >& /dev/null; }
```

Found here: https://clburlison.com/preview-files-from-terminal/

Comment: This is the current best answer. What a useful alias!